# Working with ObjectAtIndex gives beyond bounds error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, nsmutablearray

I want to do something really simple but I get an error, what I'm missing?

```
int i;
int count;

TutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Animals *aAnimal = (Animals *)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex:i];
count = [animals count];


if (i < count)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",aAnimal.animalName);
}
```

ERROR:

```
 '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 22510243 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

The 0...5 is correct! There are only 6 values in the array.

And use

```
NSLog(@"%@",aAnimal.animalName);
```

out of the if function returns the right value, when I also change the i to 0 ofcourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise i.

```
int i = 0;
```

By default ints are not set to zero or anything sensible. You can check this by adding a line such as:

```
NSLog(@"Value of i without initialising is: %d", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

please intialise your mutable array-

```
appDelegate.animals=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)array];
```

and check out your array, have you mention nil object at the end of your array elements-

```
NSMutableArray* animals=[[NSMutableArray alloc] 
initWithObjects:@"one 1",@"two 2",nil];
```

Comment: I found the problem my count was returning zero! Thanx!